# Completeness Soundness Example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am confused between Completeness and Soundness.

I know that in **Soundness** every derivable formula is true and in **completeness** every true formula is derivable.

Provide Simple examples(in layman terms) of system which is:

1. Complete and Sound
2. Complete but Not Sound
3. Not Complete but Sound
4. Not Complete and Not Sound

Comment: The Pressburg-arithmetic is complete and sound (an example for $1.$)

Comment: Goedel has proven that the peano axioms (or the zermelo-fraenkel-choice axioms (in short (ZFC) ) cannot be both sound and complete. If a system is not sound , it is complete because everything can be derived from a contradiction. So, $4.$ is impossible. Hopefully, the peano axioms and ZFC are examples for $3.$

Comment: @Peter One has to distinguish between completeness of a proof system and completeness of a theory.  Goedel proved that there exist sound and complete proof systems for first-order logic.  He later proved that there is no complete first-order theory of arithmetic (with multiplication).

Comment: @Peter I meant "sound and complete" first-order theory of arithmetic.

Comment: Contrary to what your text probably says, completeness and soundness are relative concepts that compare 2 logics.

Answer (score 9):

For formal proof systems that try to prove purely logical theorems:

1. Pretty much any formal derivation system in any text as these are usually vetted to be both sound (whatever you formally derive is in fact a logical theorem) and complete (the rules are 'strong' or 'powerful' enough to prove every logical theorem).
2. A proof system that contains the Hokus Ponens inference rule: from nothing derive any statement $P$. This system can formally derive *everything*, so it can prove all logical theorems (hence it is complete) but also statements that are not logical theorems (hence it is not sound). It is *too* powerful!
3. A proof system that contains no inference rules at all. Since it cannot prove anything at all, it follows that it can't prove anything that is not true, so it is sound. On the other hand, it can't prove any of the true things either (and there is at least one logical truth), so it is not complete. It is too *weak*.
4. A proof system that contains exactly one inference rule Modus Bogus: from $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q$ infer $P$. This system can derive falsehoods, while at the same time is unable to prove various truths. So it is neither sound nor complete. ... It is pretty useless, really.

Comment: A proof system is characterized by its rules of inference, but also by its axioms.  In (4), if we take propositional tautologies to be axioms, then we have a complete proof system.  Indeed, $\psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$ and $\neg\psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi)$ are both tautologies and by Modus Bogus (I like that name!) one infers both $\psi$ and $\neg\psi$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Nice application of Modus Bogus! Anyway, what I had in mind was a derivational system that has no axioms, just inference rules.  But I could have done the same with an axiom system: I would throw out the traditional axioms, and replace it with a single Modus Bogus axiom $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$.